# Creating XML file with minidom appendChild() in external function

Tags: python, xml, minidom

For creating a XML file with Python, I am using minidom in the class WriteXMLClass. The function `appendChild()` from minidom will appear quiet often, so I want to  store it in an external function. But then the reference to `self.base` is lost and I get no output.

This should be the result XML file:

```
<ROOT>
       <CHILD1>
        </CHILD1>
       <CHILD2>
        </CHILD2>
</ROOT>
```

Code I got so far:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

    class WriteXMLClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
             self.base = dom.Document()

        def AddEmptyTag(self, tagname):
             tag = self.base.createElement(tagname)
             return tag    

        def CreateXML(self, Objects):
             self.base = dom.Document()

             tagdict = self.base.createElement('ROOT')
             self.base.appendChild(tagdict)

             tagCHILD1 = self.AddEmptyTag('CHILD1')
             tagdict.appendChild(tagCHILD1)
             tagCHILD2 = self.AddEmptyTag('CHILD2')
             tagdict.appendChild(tagCHILD2)

             self.base.writexml(PATH, "", "\t", "\r\n", "utf-8")
```

How could I use `appendChild()` in `AddEmptyTag()` like this:??

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

    class WriteXMLClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
             self.base = dom.Document()

        def AddEmptyTag(self, tagname, PARENTNODE):   #NEW
             tag = self.base.createElement(tagname)
             PARENTNODE.appendChild(tag)              #NEW
             return tag    

        def CreateXML(self, Objects):
             self.base = dom.Document()

             tagdict = self.base.createElement('ROOT')
             self.base.appendChild(tagdict)

             tagCHILD = self.AddEmptyTag('CHILD1', tagdict) #NEW
             tagCHILD2 = self.AddEmptyTag('CHILD2', tagdict) #NEW

             self.base.writexml(PATH, "", "\t", "\r\n", "utf-8")
```

Comment: What is `tagdict` supposed to be? Should you be using `self.tagdict`?

Comment: it is just a reference of the `ROOT` tag.

Comment: But you're trying to refer to it in `AddEmptyTag` where it isn't defined.

Comment: is not it possible to pass `tagdict` by reference to `AddEmptyTag`?

Comment: You could pass it as a parameter, but you're not doing that at the moment. You can only pass by assignment in Python.

Comment: how would that looks like in this example?

Comment: Currently, you're passing `tagdict` as the `PARENTNODE` parameter, but also trying to access `tagdict` directly. I don't know why, and it's not clear enough to me what you're trying to achieve to offer any further advice.